# Finding blank User Agents and spoofed UA in access logs

Tags: apache, logging, awk, user-agent, access-log

I'm trying to find any blank user agents and traces of spoofed user agents in my apache access logs.

Here's a typical line from my Access Log: (with IP and domain redacted)

```
x.x.x.x - - [10/Nov/2012:16:48:38 -0500] "GET /YLHicons/reverbnation50.png HTTP/1.1" 304 - "http://www.example.com/newaddtwitter.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/534.7 ZemanaAID/FFFF0077"
```

For blank user agents I'm trying to do this:

```
awk -F\" '($6 ~ /^-?$/)' /www/logs/www.example.com-access.log | awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq
```

For finding info about UA's I'm running this: (Gives me the amount of hits each unique UA has)

```
awk -F\" '{print $6}' /www/logs/www.example.com-access.log | sort | uniq -c | sort -fr
```

What can I do differently to make these commands stronger and more thought out, while giving me the best information I can to combat bots and other scums of the Internet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't use `\"` as a field separator.  CLF is constructed well enough that if you separate on whitespace, field 12 is the start of your user agent.  If `$12 == '""'`, the user agent is blank.

Remember that `awk` can accept standard input.  So you can have "live" monitoring of your Apache log with:

```sh
$ tail -F /path/to/access.log | /path/to/awkscript
```

Just remember that when invoked this way, an awk script will never reach its `END`.  But you can process lines as they are added to the log by Apache.

Something like this might help.  Add to it as you see fit.

```awk
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
  mailcmd="Mail -s \"Security report\" webmaster@example.com";
}

# Detect empty user-agent
$12 == "" {
  report="Empty user agent from " $1 "\n";
}

# Detect image hijacking
$7 ~ /\.(png|jpg)$/ && $11 !~ /^http:\/\/www.example.com\// {
  report=report "Possible hijacked image from " $1 " (" $11 " -> " $7 ")\n";
}

# Detect too many requests per second from one host
thissecond != $4 {
  delete count;
  thissecond=$4;
}
{
  count[$1]++;
  for (ip in count) {
    if (count[ip] > 100) {
      report=report "Too many requests from " $1 "\n";
      delete(count[ip]);  # Avoid too many reports
    }
  }
}

# Send report, if there is one
length(report) {
  print report | mailcmd;    # Pipe output through a command.
  close(mailcmd);            # Closing the pipe sends the mail.
  report="";                 # Blank the report, ready for next.
}
```

Note that counting requests within a particular second is only marginally helpful; if you have a lot of traffic from China, or university/corporate networks behind firewalls, then many requests might appear to come from a single IP address.  And the `Mail` command isn't a great way to handle notifications; I include it here only for demonstration purposes.  YMMV, salt to taste.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but this is cool. Definitely getting bookmarked for future use. Thanks!